# Populating columns and rows of HTML table with MySQL data

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

Not sure how to word this question well but hopefully someone can help... I'm trying to select data from a MySQL database and output it to a HTML table using PHP whereby data from the query forms the column headings and rows. The data in my 'budget' table looks like:

[image]

I want to output the Customer in the rows, Week in the columns and sum of the Qty as the data. So far, I have:

```
<? $q1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT customer, week, sum(qty) AS qty FROM budget GROUP BY week, customer"); ?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <? while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row1['customer']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row1['week']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row1['qty']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <? } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This produces a table similar to the original MySQL table format but what i'm trying to achieve is:

[image]

The week selection will be dynamic so it could be 4 or 36 weeks that i'd want in the columns depending on their selection in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mysqli_fetch_row`. Each row is an array that can be accessed by indices. It looks like: `Array ( [0] => A [1] => 1 [2] => 52 ... )`

Create a new **two dimensional** array that looks like

```
$arr["A"] = [
  1 => ...
  2 => ...
]
```

### Example

**PHP**

```
<?php

// $conn = ...
$q1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT customer, week, sum(qty) AS qty FROM budget GROUP BY week, customer");
$res1 = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($q1)) 
{
    array_push($res1, $row);
}

$title = "Customer";
$max = $res1[count($res1) - 1][1];
$res2 = [];
// Index for "title" ("A", "B", "C", ...)
$i = 0;

foreach ($res1 as $row) {
    $res2[$row[$i]][$row[1]] = $row[2];
}

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $title ?></td>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++): ?>
                <td><?= $i ?></td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($res2 as $key => $values): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $key ?></td>
                <?php foreach ($values as $value): ?>
                    <td><?= $value ?></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```